# Assign new bash variable for each iteration in a for loop

Tags: bash, loops, variables, for-loop

I have `pdb_lists.log` as follows:

```
cat pdb_lists.log
'PDB1','PDB2'
```

I need to check TDE status of each PDB from above list and assign to new variable

```
 for i in $( cat $SQL_SPOOL_LOG_DIR/pdb_lists.log | sed "s/,/ /g" | sed "s/'/ /g")
        do
 PDB_TE_STATUS=$ORACLE_HOME/bin/sqlplus '/as sysdba' << EOF 
            whenever sqlerror exit failure
            connect / as sysdba
            set head off
            set pagesize 0
            set linesize 145
            set feedback off
            alter session set container=$i;
    show con_name;
            spool $SQL_SPOOL_LOG_DIR/pdb_te_enable_status.log
            select status from v\encryption_wallet;
            spool off
 EOF
 CDB_CREATOR_PDB=$ORACLE_HOME/bin/sqlplus '/as sysdba' << EOF 
            whenever sqlerror exit failure
            connect / as sysdba
            set head off
            set pagesize 0
            set linesize 145
            set feedback off
            alter session set container=$i;
    show con_name;
            spool $SQL_SPOOL_LOG_DIR/pdb_cdb_creator_pdb_status.log
            select distinct CREATOR_PDBNAME from v\$encryption_keys where CREATOR_PDBNAME not like 'CDB$ROOT%' and KEY_ID is not null;
            spool off
  EOF
  done
```

Once I have a new variable assigned for each PDB, then I need run based on the value to respective sql.

Comment: See [BashFAQ #6](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/006)

Comment: ...also, as an aside -- [Don't Read Lines With `for`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor). See [BashFAQ #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) for a discussion of best practices for working with file I/O. Consider also running your code through http://shellcheck.net/ and fixing the quoting bugs that finds.

Answer (score 1):

Use an associative array. Associative arrays (also known as maps or dictionaries) behave like arrays, but allow arbitrary strings as indices.

```
declare -A status
for pdb in ...; do
   status["$pdb"]=...
done
```

To read the status of a PDB (whatever that is), use `${status[nameOfThePDB]}`.